# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected (T_STRING)

Tags: php

I'm trying to bring a old script back to life but i'm not the best at php but practice makes prefect.

Could someone explain or point out what is causing this error i'm getting below.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '''' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\install\step2check.php on line 16

```
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "<br><br><br><br><center>
<h1><font color='red'>Failed to connect to MySQL</font></h1>
<h2>Please go back and check your MySQL Connection infomation</h2>
</center>
<a href='index.php' class='Start'>Back to Start</a>";
}
else {
#########################
## POPULATE connect.php##
#########################
file_put_contents("../connect.php", "");
$filename = '../connect.php';
$somecontent = '<?php
$db_host        = \''.$POSThost.'\';
$db_user        = \''.$POSTuser.'\';
$db_pass        = \''.$POSTpass.'\';
$db_database        = \''.$POSTdatabase.'\'; 
$link = @mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die(\'Unable to establish a DB connection\');

mysql_query("SET NAMES \'utf8\'");
mysql_select_db($db_database,$link);
?>';
```

I hope someone can help.

Comment: I think, there might be a '; missing at the end to end the assignment of $somecontent.

Comment: `$somecontent` has not an end `'`

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to write php from within php code (if this is not a setup script)

Comment: which is line 16 and the file of the error?

Comment: Sorry forgot to put the ending :(

Comment: line 16 - $somecontent = '<?php

Comment: so the rror is the ' ?  or was a typo?

Comment: Learn about heredoc: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc.

Comment: `\''.$POSThost.'\';` - why are you escaping the `'` before the string starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//why set to a php variable to hold other php variables that are defined from even other PHP variables? No need to complicate things, and cause extra errors in the meantime. Try this:

```
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "<br><br><br><br><center>
<h1><font color='red'>Failed to connect to MySQL</font></h1>
<h2>Please go back and check your MySQL Connection infomation</h2>
</center>
<a href='index.php' class='Start'>Back to Start</a>";
}
else {
#########################
## POPULATE connect.php##
#########################
file_put_contents("../connect.php", "");
$filename = '../connect.php';
$db_host        = $POSThost;
$db_user        = $POSTuser;
$db_pass        = $POSTpass;
$db_database        = $POSTdatabase; 
$link = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die(\'Unable to establish a DB connection\');

mysql_query("SET NAMES \'utf8\'");
mysql_select_db($db_database,$link);
}
?>
```